# Change the TextBlock Foreground from ComboBox over Event fire only in a Style.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I have a Style xaml without a .cs File

Below you can find a part of my code. There you can find the `TextBlock`. I would like to change the fontcolor there when the user takes an action (hover, click, whatever). As you can see there is the VisualStateManager who deals with the events of the `Combobox`. Is it possible to overwrite the foreground in the Visual state manager (for example: If "click" then red, if "hover" then blue)?

I've spent many time to find a solution for my problem but there is no solution in view...

Can anybody help my? Attention the solution is only in a xaml file implemented that holds all styles from my controls.

```
<Border x:Name="ContentPresenterBorder"
        BorderBrush="Blue">

    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="DropDownToggle"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Margin="0"
                      Style="{StaticResource comboToggleStyle}"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                      HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                      Background="White"
                      BorderBrush="{x:Null}">
        </ToggleButton>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock x:Name="TextTextBlock"
                       Text="{TemplateBinding Tag}"
                       FontWeight="Bold"
                       Foreground="White"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                       Effect="{StaticResource MenuDropShadowEffect}"
                       IsHitTestVisible="False">
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
                                <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Foreground">
                                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF04A925" />
                                    </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                                </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
                                <ei:ChangePropertyAction PropertyName="Foreground">
                                    <ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="Black"/>
                                    </ei:ChangePropertyAction.Value>
                                </ei:ChangePropertyAction>
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>


            <Path x:Name="BtnArrow"
                  Stretch="Uniform"
                  Height="4"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                  Margin="0,0,6,0"
                  Width="8"
                  Fill="White"
                  Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z "
                  Effect="{StaticResource MenuDropShadowEffect}"
                  IsHitTestVisible="False">
            </Path>


        </StackPanel>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                          Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </Grid>

</Border>

<Rectangle x:Name="DisabledVisualElement"
           Fill="White"
           RadiusX="3"
           RadiusY="3"
           IsHitTestVisible="false"
           Opacity="0" />
<Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement"
           Stroke="{x:Null}"
           StrokeThickness="1"
           RadiusX="2"
           RadiusY="2"
           Margin="1"
           IsHitTestVisible="false"
           Opacity="0"
           Fill="{x:Null}" />
<Border x:Name="ValidationErrorElement"
        Visibility="Collapsed"
        BorderBrush="#FFDB000C"
        BorderThickness="1"
        CornerRadius="1">
    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip x:Name="validationTooltip"
                 DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                 Template="{StaticResource ValidationToolTipTemplate}"
                 Placement="Right"
                 PlacementTarget="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
            <ToolTip.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Canvas.Loaded">
                    <BeginStoryboard>
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip"
                                                           Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsHitTestVisible">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                        <System:Boolean>true</System:Boolean>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </EventTrigger>
            </ToolTip.Triggers>
        </ToolTip>
    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
    <Grid Height="12"
          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
          Margin="1,-4,-4,0"
          VerticalAlignment="Top"
          Width="12"
          Background="Transparent">

    </Grid>
</Border>
<Popup x:Name="Popup"
       Margin="0,1,0,0">
    <Border x:Name="PopupBorder"
            Height="Auto"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            CornerRadius="3"
            BorderBrush="#FFC1C1C1"
            BorderThickness="0,0,1,1">
        <Border.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1"
                                 StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFFFFFF"
                              Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FFFEFEFE"
                              Offset="1" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Border.Background>
        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                      BorderThickness="0"
                      Padding="1">
            <ItemsPresenter />
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Border>
</Popup>

<ContentControl x:Name="HeaderText" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                    HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                    Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
        <ContentPresenter.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="0"
                                Color="#FF666666"
                                Direction="90"
                                ShadowDepth="1"/>
        </ContentPresenter.Effect>
    </ContentPresenter>
</ContentControl>

<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
            <Storyboard>

            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver" >
            <!--<Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderText" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Control.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                    Duration="0" To="#FF000000"/>
            </Storyboard>-->
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="Content" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000" Value="#FFFF0000"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>-->

                <!--<ColorAnimation
                    BeginTime="00:00:00"
                    Duration="00:00:00.0010000"
                    From="#FFFFFFFF" To="#FF000000" 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Content" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Foreground).Color"                                            
                />-->
                <ColorAnimation
                    BeginTime="00:00:00"
                    Duration="00:00:00.0010000"
                    From="#FFFFFFFF" To="#FF000000" 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Content" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).Color"                                            
                />
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="DisabledVisualElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"
                                          Value=".55" />
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)">
                    <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"
                                          Value="1" />
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderText" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000" Value="#FFFF0000"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
        <VisualState x:Name="FocusedDropDown">
            <Storyboard>

                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                               Duration="00:00:00.0010000"
                                               Storyboard.TargetName="TextTextBlock"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Direction)">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"
                                          Value="-90" />
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                              Duration="00:00:00.0010000"
                                              Storyboard.TargetName="TextTextBlock"
                                              Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.Color)">
                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"
                                         Value="#FF333333" />
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                               Duration="00:00:00.0010000"
                                               Storyboard.TargetName="TextTextBlock"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.ShadowDepth)">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"
                                          Value="1" />
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                               Duration="00:00:00.0010000"
                                               Storyboard.TargetName="TextTextBlock"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Effect).(DropShadowEffect.BlurRadius)">
                    <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00"
                                          Value="2" />
                </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="00:00:00"
                                               Storyboard.TargetName="PopupBorder"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <!--<ColorAnimation
                    BeginTime="00:00:00"
                    Duration="00:00:00.0010000"
                    Storyboard.TargetName="Content" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                    From="White" To="Black"                                                                     
                />-->
                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="00:00:00"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="HeaderText" 
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)">
                    <SplineColorKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:00.4000000" Value="#FFFF0000"/>
                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ValidationStates">
        <VisualState x:Name="Valid" />
        <VisualState x:Name="InvalidUnfocused">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="InvalidFocused">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ValidationErrorElement"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="validationTooltip"
                                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsOpen">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">` for mouse hover.

[WPF: Change background color of border on left mouse button down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2208447/wpf-change-background-color-of-border-on-left-mouse-button-down) for mouse click

Answer (score 0):

hei guys.. i could solve it by myself!
the mistake was:

Storyboard.TargetName="Content"... should have been referring to "textBlock" of course....
hope to be helpful for someone else as well...